# count the number of words in java

Tags: java

```
  Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    char ch;
    int W=0;
    String s;
    System.out.println("enter a String:");
    s = sc.nextLine();
    for(int i = 0;i<s.length();i++)
    {
        ch = s.charAt(i);

        if(Character.isWhitespace(ch))
        W++;
    }

    System.out.println(W+1);
    }
    }

 when i am executing above program with the
 input :COMPUTER APPLICATION 
 its giving correct output no of words 2
in case if i entered
input: COMPUTER APPLICATION 1 
answer should be for the no of words 2 but answer is displaying 3 program code also counts last 1.
```

In my knowledge 1 is not word, word means a set of character answer should be 2. 1 should not be count.
    Take other input
    input: COMPUTER APPLICATION 12
    now for above input answer for the frequency of the word 3 fine because last word 12 is word means 
    two character are there.Please i don't want use split function.

Comment: Your code won't compile. Please fix it and indent your code properly. For showing input/output use blockquote, not `code` to easily distinguish between them.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the split method? But the reason you get three words is that you've defined 1 as a word.

Comment: Also, all your questions are down-voted, you are at a risk of question ban: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th/

Comment: harshal parekh fixed the error

Comment: It still does not compile.

Comment: Nowhere in your program are you checking that the characters entered are not numeric, so you can't expect your program to output 2 for the second case. Use Character.isLetter

Comment: Any reason why you don't want to use `.split()` - this is a perfect usecase for it.

Comment: now i fixed the errors in the code

Comment: harshal parekh i am teacher. i know how to use split, but what about students?

Comment: Why don't you teach the students how to use `.split()`? As the requirements are any solution without `split` would be complicated.

Comment: harshal any idea to avoid 1 as a word?

Comment: @Aman you can check my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

1) Make a variable that will be activated in you confront a number

```
boolean confront_number = false;
```

2) On your loop , if you keep confronting a number ( not a word with number ) : then it will be true

3) Lastly , on your condition , you will have to increment only if that variable is false

```
if(Character.isWhitespace(ch) && confront_number==false)
    W++;
```